# Botão "Play/Pause" - Como reiniciar a reprodução?

Tags: javascript, script, button, áudio

Eu fiz um simples botão "*play/pause*" para áudio, com o seguinte script:

```
<audio id="myAudio"         
src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
if (isPlaying) {
myAudio.pause()
} else {
myAudio.play();
}
};
myAudio.onplaying = function() {
isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
isPlaying = false;
};
</script>
```

Porém, na verdade gostaria que ao clicar no botão "*play/pause*" ao invés de pausar, reiniciasse do '0' a reprodução. Alguma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione `myAudio.currentTime = 0;` à função `myAudio.onpause`:

```js
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
   if (isPlaying) {
      myAudio.pause()
   } else {
     myAudio.play();
   }
};

myAudio.onplaying = function() {
   isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
   myAudio.currentTime = 0;
   isPlaying = false;
};
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" preload="auto" controls>
   <source src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Obrigado, implementado com sucesso!

Comment: @dib Valeu!!!!!